# Playing video with QT

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, video-capture

I want to create an application through which i need to play a video file with audio(need to play almost all kinds of videos).

I need it for Windows and Linux(atleast for windows).

I am planning to use QT or any other package?.  How to do?

I need a GUI as
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mA883X4uaHk (pl watch from .35s)

My Project Description:
  1.Need to play a video in a thread
  2.In an another thread. Parallely, need to capture the webcam video and need to process the
    webcam frames with Opencv algorithms which plots the graphs.

Planning to duplicate the youtube video application. I have to use threads as well. And opencv supports QT .

What have i done:
 Used Java Media Framework to playback which fails as it dosn't support all the formats.

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCV u can do sth like:

```
Mat frame;
VideoCapture vid("your_filename"); // open video file
if(!vid.isOpened()) // check if we succeeded
    return -1;
vid >> frame; //extract a frame
```

Later u can create QImage and initialize it with frame data, like:

```
QImage *img = new QImage(frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

If Im not worng I just had a problem, that first taken frame was black, so I needed to do sth like: `vid >> frame; Sleep(1); vid >> frame;` Just in case it happens to u too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. I need to play audio as well. Please gimme a suggestion.

Comment: I didnt work with audio but visit this manual: http://docs.opencv.org/index.html Its very friendly and u can find lots of examples + tutorials there.

Comment: +1 Ya opencv does not handle audio. Need to go for FFMPEG/SDL with multi threading. ITs complex to handle audio video sync as well.! It will be gr8 if you/anybody aqdvice me to handle it through som other QT based package.!

Comment: So to display pure video, use Phonon Module, which Zlatomir suggested. And to work on camera's frames in OpenCV, u can use my solution, just change source of video from `VideoCapture vid("your_filename");` to `VideoCapture cam(0);`, which opens default webcam.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Qt version 5 you can use [QMediaPlayer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qml-qtmultimedia5-mediaplayer.html) and with version 4 you can use [phonon](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-module.html) module (look at examples, if i remember correctly they contain a simple video player).

Comment: QMediaPlayer and phonon requiers external codecks for playing video.

Answer (score 1):

Well , if you are willing to use Qt5 then Multimedia module has everything you need. You can access each frame of a video / camera and process it.You can use the same video surface to play video and and display web cam frames. There are simple examples in Qt5 multimedia widgets example directory , you can refer.